# Applying context of functions to javascript variable?

Tags: javascript

How do I apply the context of functions to any javascript object? So I can change what "this" means in the functions.

For Example:

```
var foo = {
    a: function() {
           alert(this.a);
      },
    b: function() {
           this.b +=1;
           alert (this.b);
      }

var moo = new Something(); // some object 
var moo.func.foo = foo; // right now this is moo.func
// how do I apply/change the context of the foo functions to moo?
// so this should equal moo
moo.a(); // this should work
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just set the function on `moo`:

```
var moo = new Something();
moo.a = foo.a;
moo.a();
```

...but if you want it inherited by all instances of `Something`, you'll need to set it on `Something.prototype`:

```
var moo;
Something.prototype = foo;
moo = new Something();
moo.a();
```

You have some issues in your definitions of `foo.a` and `foo.b`, as they both are self-references `this.b +=1` will especially cause issues, so you may want to change the functions to something like `this._b +=` and `alert(this._b)`, or use differently named functions.

Comment: +1 I think the [[prototype]] route is desired; it looks like a jQuery-emulation approach.